# c++ adding to the end of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I"m new to this so I'm barely learning how to implement a linked list. My program crashes when i input a number. I'm suppose to add the node to the back of the list.

This is the node

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};
```

this is the add function

```
void Add(node* &head, int newdata)
{
    //create a new node to hold the data with a terminal (NULL) next pointer           
       node *tmp = new node;
       tmp->data = newdata;
       tmp->next;
       node *current = head;
    //check whether head has been initialized (is NULL)
    // if not, make the new node head and set prev
       if ( head != NULL)
       {
            tmp = head;
            tmp->prev = NULL;
       } 

    //if head has been initialized
    //find the end of the chain with a pointer
      else
      {
           while (current->next != NULL )
           {
                current = current->next;
           }
      }

    //add the new node on to the last node in the list
    //set pointers both forward and backwards
     tmp = current;
     tmp->prev = current->prev->next;
     tmp->next = current->next;



}
```

Comment: If (head) is NULL, then (current) also will be initialized as NULL, and then your while(current->next != NULL) loop condition will be dereferencing a NULL pointer, and you'll crash there.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, you need to set `tmp->next` and `tmp->prev` to NULL.
Garbage pointers are going to kill you, every time.

Then you seem to think `head == NULL` means it's been initialized, when it probably means the opposite.

At the end, you set `tmp = current;`, so you're throwing away the node you want to add.

Try to work through those last three lines again.

Also, step it with a debugger, in case you have trouble seeing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you got some odd stuff going on in  that `add` function, here is something that might help you understand the process:

```
 void add(node* &head, int dataToAdd){
    node* newNode = new node();
    newNode->data = dataToAdd;

    if(!head){ // checking to see if head was passed in or is null
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    node* current = head;
    node* next = current->next;
     // iterate through the list till next == Null( hits 1 after the end)
    while(current->next){
       current = next;
       next = next->next;
    }

    //Set the end of the list to the newly added node
    next = newNode;
    next->prev = current;

 }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `while` loop implementation has a time complexity of `O(n)`, which defeats the purpose of creating a doubly linked list.

Comment: It depends on your inputs. If you don't have a pointer to 'tail' then you don't really have any other choice. Another point, related but not exactly to the question, if you are adding to the middle based on some conditional, then you would still need to iterate through the list.

Answer (score 0):

What is this line is supposed to do?

```
tmp->next;
```

Working with linked lists can be a real brain exercise from time to time. I would suggest you initialize the pointers to NULL directly. And regarding the last three lines, they need to be thought through once more.

```
 tmp = current; //This discards your newly created node, which results in a memory leak
 tmp->prev = current->prev->next; // The previous node is simply 'current'
 tmp->next = current->next; // You know that the next node will be NULL
```

The `current` node also needs to know what the new `current->next` will be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it more like this instead:

```
void Add(node* &head, int newdata)
{
    //create a new node to hold the data with a terminal (NULL) next pointer           
    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->data = newdata;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    tmp->prev = NULL;

    if (!head)
        head = tmp;
    else
    {
        //find the end of the chain with a pointer
        node *last = head;
        while (last->next != NULL )
            last = last->next;

        //add the new node on to the last node in the list
        //set pointers both forward and backwards
        last->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = last;
    }
}
```

If you keep track of the last node along with the head, your inserts will be much faster as you will not have to iterate the entire list every time, eg:

```
struct list
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
};

void Add(list &l, int newdata)
{
    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->data = newdata;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (!l.head)
        l.head = tmp;

    tmp->prev = l.tail;
    if (tmp->prev)
        tmp->prev->next = tmp;

    l.tail = tmp;
}
```

That being said, since you are using C++, you really should be using `std::list`, which handles all of this for you:

```
#include <list>

std::list<int> mylist;
mylist.push_back(12345);
// etc...
```